# Removing email from package testing using testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I'm developing a package that uses your personal email to log in to a website to download some data. When I test the functions using `testthat` I use my email, but I wouldn't want my email to be uploaded into Github because other users might use it to download data.

Is there a way for the testing to be done successfully without showing my email?

Comment: Store it in an environment variable and pull from that environment variable on testing. Search for `~/.Renviron` for how to do that.

Comment: Would that allow CRAN to also run the tests?

Comment: You should not have tests that login to external network resources on CRAN. Do that on Travis-CI (they support secure environment variables but there are other things you can do on Travis as well w/r/t secure data), have a badge in your README and inform put `skip_on_cran()` for those tests and tell CRAN you use Travis and provide a link to the Travis builds in your e-mail submission to CRAN.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed. If you write it as an answer I'll up vote it.

Comment: For ^^, Ref: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/sergeant/blob/master/cran-comments.md and the test suite there (it's breaking on Travis right now due to a problem with an Ubuntu dependency, not an R pkg issue). A few more of my pkgs are configured the same way as well (most of the API ones, in fact)

Comment: Thx. I'll do that when internet and power are restored :-) (I live in Maine where 300K of us are out of commission at the moment) Cutting & pasting from comments to an answer on a phone is a frustrating endeavour.